# Plugin [repository-hdfs] is incompatible with Elasticsearch [2.1.1]. Was designed for version [2.2.0-SNAPSHOT]

Tags: hadoop, plugins, elasticsearch, hdfs

I'm trying to integrate HDFS with Elastic Search to use it as the repository for snapshots. You can find the documentation [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/tree/master/repository-hdfs).
Hadoop is already installed and running on my system so I'm using the light version. I'm installing the plugin offline after downloading it's zip from [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-repository-hdfs/2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/).
When I try installing using the command

> bin/plugin install file:/filepath

I get the following error:

> ERROR: Plugin [repository-hdfs] is incompatible with Elasticsearch [2.1.1]. Was designed for version [2.2.0-SNAPSHOT].

Can someone tell what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin expects version 2.2.0 of ElasticSearch, which has not yet been released. So unzip the plugin, edit the plugin-descriptor.properties file to specify the correct version of ElasticSearch you are using. Zip the folder again and give the path of this modified zip as mentioned in the question. Works like a charm. 
For more information see
(https://discuss.elastic.co/t/plugin-repository-hdfs-is-incompatible-with-elasticsearch-2-1-1-was-designed-for-version-2-2-0-snapshot/39846/5)